# How do I create an instance of a designed object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, nsopenglview

I'm writing an application that will require multiple windows.
I've designed how I want my window to look in Interface Builder and when I start my application it all looks as it should.
I've got a large library of C++ code that I've been making use of and I've managed to integrate it nicely.
However, I have functions that I use (in my cross-platform system) to create windows - but how do I create a new/second instance of the window I designed in Interface Builder?

For example, I have an NSWindow, which contains an NSView, which contains an OpenGL view.
At launch, my window (and it's contents) are created and shown wonderfully.

At some point when this window is running I will want to respond to some user input and display a second window with an NSView and OpenGL view (exactly as I designed it in IB). How do I create this second instance?

I am new to Mac programming and appreciate that may have misunderstood some concepts of how this actually works - corrections are most certainly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your have to reload the nib containing the window. The easiest way to do this, is to instantiate a [window controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with that nib.